# Can I input Chinese character in Unity's dash?

Tags: unity

I use Ubuntu in Chinese language.

And a lot of programme on my Ubuntu have chinese name.

I can open it in Terminal. But I can not search them in Unity.

[image: a busy cat]

Because in Unity's dash, I can only input English, can not use input method. So can not input Chinese character.

I use Chinese as my mother language. And I use Chinese input method a lot.

Can someone help me to let me input Chinese character in Unity's dash?

I really like Ubuntu and want to use it more frequently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at this bug? [[dash] wrong search result of Unity in Chinese](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/745243)

Answer (score 5):

Unity doesn't support Chinese, but you can use Kupfer, which can launch programs with Chinese names.

1. 你首先要安装kupfer (First you need to install kupfer)

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kupfer-team/ppa`

   `sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get install kupfer`
2. 然后你需要打开kupfer. 你可以在Unity Dash里面找到 (Then, you need to open kupfer. You can find it in the Unity dash)
3. 按照下面的图片来做 (Do the following steps)：

[image: Right click the tray icon]

[image: Select tab]

[image: Press super + space]

按Windows key + Space (Hold down the windows key and press space)

[image: click exit]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is fixed in 12.04. Just use ibus for input method, use Ctrl+Space to change to Chinese, and enjoy!! I could not post images, but it works for me well. Sorry~